# Multiple errors in the string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
NSString *p = [[storagePath retain] autorelease];
```

1)ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'.

2)ARC forbids explicit message send of 'retain'.

3) autorelease is unavailable.not available in automatic reference counting mode .

4) retain is unavailable.not available in automatic reference counting mode .

The string has multiple errors. Suggest issues and rectification.?

Comment: If this is coming from a tutorial, it is outdated. ObjC now uses ARC to manage memory, rendering `retain`, `autorelease`, and `release` obsolete. See the posted answers or the [documentation (in Swift 2, however)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

**ARC** refers for (**Automatic Reference Counting**) which is responsible
 for memory releasing safely.

The bellow line means:

```
//NSString *p = [[storagePath retain] autorelease];
```

"[storagePath retain]" means  the variable **storagePath** increments it's reference by adding 1.

So, it's need to release whenever it will no longer be used. **autorelease** will do this task automatically.

But when **apple** introduced **ARC** do always **autorelease** everything (except: complex loop)

You don't need to use **autorelease** and now **retain** property of a **NSString** class has no longer exist.So, need not do **retain** of a **string**. Just simply write the following

```
NSString *p = storagePath;
```

Comment: Because ARC do all for you of releasing memory safely

Answer (score 1):

(ARC is "Automatic Reference Counting", a new feature comes underwith  iOS 5 and onwards).  Therefore you do not need to manually retain or release.

```
// directly you want to access

NSString *p = storagePath;
```

> You can either remove your retain call all together or turn off ARC by doing the following:
>
> Click on the name of the project on the navigation view in the left side, go to Targets -> Build Phases and add `-fno-objc-arc` to the "compiler flags" for any relevant files.